# Extracting files out of network traffic

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I know Scapy library has a huge capabilities; but am trying to figure out how can I carve files out a network stream by Scapy? This is includes files sent by encrypted connection "https"

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "carve files out of a network stream"? Just dump a network stream into a file or reconstruct files by analyzing a network stream? And wrt https, you may want to research MITM

Comment: @fvu reconstruct files by analyzing a network stream. What I want to do is to create a tool to extract files from a network stream then analyze it by YARA

Comment: The question needs a lot of work. If HTTPS it there a successful MITM attack? Is the traffic of interest available at your computer given the way switched work?

Comment: @zaph I know it needs a lot of work, I just need to know if it possible to do anything like that and I will do the research if the answer is yes

Comment: The answer is yes, however when you work with eg https you will have to insert yourself as man in the middle (like Fiddler does, btw)

Comment: It may not be possible to perform a MITM attack, if the certificate is pinned MITM will not be possible. If you are just a node on a switch only limited traffic will be available, basically packets sent to your computer. With WiFi OTOH you have access to view all packets.

Comment: @fuv thank you for your reply, I found this module which provide SSL/TLS capabilities to Scapy 
https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls
Can I use it to dissect a saved pcap file instead of MITM?

Comment: @zaph "mitm" and "mitm attack" are two different worlds, I was focusing on legit applications of mitm like debugging aids (eg, Fiddler does it) and interception for web security purposes. These are lot easier than the attack subclass :)